# Why observer method is called twice?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have the following method that returns observer, but it is called twice:

```js
public getClassesAndSubjects(school: number, whenDate: string): Observable<ClassesAndSubjects[]> {

    console.log('1');

    const observable = this.classService.GetClassesAndSubjects(school, whenDate);

    console.log("2");

    observable.subscribe(data => {
        if (!data.hasOwnProperty('errors')) {
        this.classesSubjects = data;

        }
    }, error => {
        console.log("ERROR loading GetClassesAndSubjects: " + error);
    });

    console.log("3");

    return observable;
}
```

I mean a line `const observable = this.classService.GetClassesAndSubjects(school, whenDate);` is called twice and send two times request to server.

Call this like:

```js
this.classInstance.getClassesAndSubjects(school, date).subscribe(value => {
    // TODO 
});
```

Comment: Where do you call `this.classInstance.getClassesAndSubjects` ?

Comment: You see this issue in your Network tab, in the developer tools of your browser ?

Comment: You subscribe to it once inside the method and presumably at least once outside... Why did you expect it to only get called once?

Comment: İ call `this.classInstance.getClassesAndSubjects` in component by click

Comment: In network I see double request to server'

Comment: You subscribe and then you return. That's fishy.

Comment: You subscribe to the observable twice so, so of course it gets called twice, observables execute everytime they're subscribed to

Comment: Hm, but I subscribe, not call this twice

Comment: you very clearly subscribe twice, once in inside of getClassesAndSubjects and then you subscribe to the returned value which is the same observable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this is happening because you subscribe to the observable twice, and observables execute every time they're subscribed to.

change this:

```
observable.subscribe(data => {
  if (!data.hasOwnProperty('errors')) {
    this.classesSubjects = data;

  }
}, error => {
  console.log("ERROR loading GetClassesAndSubjects: " + error);
});
```

to this:

```
observable.do(data => {
  if (!data.hasOwnProperty('errors')) {
    this.classesSubjects = data;

  }
});
```

this way you're just adding an operator onto your stream that won't execute till you subscribe to it in your return.

Comment: Will try, did not know about this

Comment: handle it when you actually subscribe.

Comment: Yes, it works for me! Thank you for short and actual solution

Comment: Can you help me with next problem: I tried to return ready array from subsribe: `public getChips(classSubjects: any) {
    Observable.of(classSubjects).map(n => {
      return {
        classNumber: n.classNumber,
        classSuffix: n.classSuffix
      };
    }).subscribe(x => console.log(x));

    return [];
  }`

Comment: subscribe doesn't return a value. If you want the value elsewhere, you should return the observable stream and subscribe to it where you want the value.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike Promises, Observable's functions are called when *subscribed* to, not when created. Each `subscription` to an Observable will cause the Observable's function to be run again.

If you want to share one Observable's emission with multiple Subscribers, use `share()`. Otherwise, if you just want to tag functionality on emissions without subscribing to the Observable, you can use `do()` (or `tap` for RxJS 5+).

Answer (score 1):

You are having trouble because you are subscribing to the same method in two places.

```js
// Your code that is subscribing to the events in two different places, which is why it is called twice.
/*public getClassesAndSubjects(school: number, whenDate: string): Observable<ClassesAndSubjects[]> {

  console.log('1');

  const observable = this.classService.GetClassesAndSubjects(school, whenDate);

  console.log("2");

  observable.subscribe(data => {
    if (!data.hasOwnProperty('errors')) {
      this.classesSubjects = data;

    }
  }, error => {
    console.log("ERROR loading GetClassesAndSubjects: " + error);
  });

  console.log("3");

  return observable;
}*/

import { tap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

public getClassesAndSubjects(school: number, whenDate: string): Observable<ClassesAndSubjects[]> {
  return this.classService.GetClassesAndSubjects(school, whenDate)
    .pipe(
      tap(data => this.classesSubjects = !data.hasOwnProperty('errors') ? data : this.classesSubjects),
      catchError(err => {
        console.log("ERROR loading GetClassesAndSubjects: " + error);
        return Observable.throw(err);
      })
    );
}
```